# Cutover migration from exchange 2007 to exchange online error

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration

Has anyone ran into this error? If so, what steps did you take to resolve it? I have about 17 users out of 150 that i cannot migrate because of this error.

"Permanent error occurred while accessing user record in Store: Error occurred while accessing user record in Store: Database xxx is not available locally, and connection to Active Manager failed: Server Locator Service call had a communication error.. "

Comment: You should absolutely be raising this with Office 365 support - they're very helpful with migrations, in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with DircSync it needed to be re-enabled and the affected mailboxes that said "in cloud" needed deleted in users on 365 then removed using object ID in AAD. once they were removed you use the miisclient.exe from you AAD install to fully import and sync the connectors. Then run a sync with your normal azure AD connect tool

1. This is all in Azure Powershell Mod, connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred
2. Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers -searchstring name@yourdomain.com | fl UserPrincipleName, ObjectID
3. Remove-MsolUser -ObjectID OBJECTID STRING HERE -RemoveFromRecycleBin -Force (Paste OBject ID in string)
4. miisclient.exe AD first full import then full sync
5. miisclient.exe AAD full import then full sync

Comment: Thanks for posting up what worked for you.  BTW you can pipe the first command to the second to save the cut'n'paste work.  `Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers -searchstring <string> | RemoveMsolUser -RemoveFromRecyclebin -Force`
You might also like to click on the tick to accept this answer as correct and delete the other answer you posted as it's not very helpful and just kind of clutters up the page

Comment: Thanks for the code, that'll help a bit! I deleted the other answer like you suggested, could use some of that Rep love! lol